# Comparing two columns in excel, one with repeating time periods, inserting blank rows and moving corresponding data

Tags: excel-formula

I have a large data set in excel and my first column consists of repeating time periods (years). I want to insert rows for the missing years and move the associated data. Here is a simpler table of the data:

```
Data:       I want to look like this:

2007 aaa    2007 aaa
2008 bbb    2008 bbb
2010 ccc    2009
2008 eee    2010 ccc
2010 ddd    2007
            2008 eee
            2009
            2010 ddd
```

When I tried the match and index functions, I got those results:
[Year Revenue Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNQzf.png)

```
where the formulas are:
in cell E:
        =IFERROR(MATCH(D2;$A$2:$A$9;0);" ")
in cell F:
        =IF(E2<>"";INDEX($A$2:$B$9;E2;1); "")
in cell G:
        =IF(E2<>"";INDEX($A$2:$B$9;E2;2); "")
```

How can I consider the repeating years and correct corresponding values?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use basic formatting options to make the post in more readable format.

Comment: Thank you, Nagama! I made some changes, if I need to I will do additional corrections to improve my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim strYear As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

          LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

          For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1

            strYear = .Range("A" & i).Value

            If .Range("A" & i - 1).Value <> strYear - 1 Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert
                .Range("A" & i).Value = strYear - 1
            End If

            Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Before Code:

[image]

After Code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In my example above 2008 and aaa are in different columns, aaa can also be numeric values. From your example, 2008 and aaa (as well as other values) appear in a single column. Is that true because the data is necessary for further analysis and I need years and the corresponding values to be in different columns?

Comment: Try the code and provide a feedback. i think that it ll works without any adjustments

Comment: I did small adjustments. Try now.

Comment: I tried the code. It works perfectly with my sample table, but when I applied it to the original file, there were some inconsistencies. The time period of the data covers 2007-2015, after the implementation of the code is also included 2006, row 28 skips 2012, and row 30 skips 2015 and starts with 2006 and so on, which violates the exact repeatability in 9 years.

Comment: Here is more information about the database - it consists of 7409 rows (enterprises) and 8 columns (variables), a survey period of 2007-2015 for each company (which is why I want to introduce the missing years in additional rows). If necessary, I can present an example table with multiple rows that is part of the original data.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a possible solution?

Comment: I tried to implement the code several times, but the only thing that happened was to add one earlier year, i.e. 2006, 2005, etc. I have not been able to have the complete sequence for 9 consecutive years.